# How to use the --abr-ladder from x265 on ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, libx265

I'm trying to find out how to use the latest [x265 abr-ladder option](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html#cmdoption-abr-ladder) on ffmpeg, which promises up to 65% time savings compared to sequential generation, according to [release notes](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/releasenotes.html#new-features), but: (1) I'm not sure if it is already available on ffmpeg or how to find out, and if it is (2) specifying the input/output inside the configuration file instead of the ffmpeg CLI causes ffmpeg to complain that required parameters are missing.

In the [x265 repository](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git/wiki/Home) there is a [example](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git/downloads/Sample_ABR_ladder_config.txt) for configuration file, but I couldn't find there or in the ffmpeg repository instructions on how to use this kind of parameter that doesn't seem to follow the CLI standards for ffmpeg. Apparently it is possible to [create multiple outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) in a single command using ffmpeg, but again I couldn't make it work.

So what I'm looking for is a usage example for the `--abr-ladder` parameter for x265. Thank you.

Comment: The x265 developers answered me in the mailing list, apparently this option is only available in the x265 application, not ffmpeg. As soon as I manage to download and test the application I'll answer my own question here..

Comment: this is a great question, saw this when running x265 --help. I'm trying to find actual x265 params, because it's a nightmare trying to generate variants to spec using ffmpeg for x265 and x264